# Opam switch not working: "error Buffer *OCaml* has no process"

Tags: switch-statement, ocaml, opam, merlin

I am on macOS 13.4, I set up my Ocaml environment with emacs but I'm still new at it so I got trouble solving some of my problems:

For the project I am working on I had to clone my working repository twice. The first repository works fine: merlin recognises the modules, I can `C-c C-l` to access the definition of objects, and the execution of the code `C-x C-e` works fine.

Dependencies:

- merlin toolkit v4.5-412
- opam v2.1.4
- dune v3.8.0
- ocaml toplevel v4.12.1

Merlin doesn't seem to work in my second repository: the libraries installed, such as Irmin or Lwt aren't recognized, they are `Not in environment` when I try `C-c C-l`. Every call to the libraries shows the error `Unbound module ...`.

Then I can't manage to execute the code with the opam switch of my second repository:

```
opam exec --switch=/Users/Louis/git/temp/learn-ocaml -- ocaml
```

in emacs returns the error

```lisp
error "Buffer *OCaml* has no process"
```

I tried to solve the problem:

```
eval $(opam env)
```

and then `M-x merlin-stop-server RET` in emacs but I have the error

```
No config found for irmin-test.ml. Try calling `dune build`.
```

I also get the error message, when I try to save a file:

```
The current Merlin configuration has been generated by another, incompatible, version of Dune. Please rebuild the project. (Using the same version of Dune as the one running the `ocaml-merlin` server.)
```

The dependencies used for compilation should be alright, and I made sure all the opam packages were installed.

I also tried to set the switch manually:

```
eval $(opam env --switch=/Users/Louis/git/temp/learn-ocaml --set-switch)
```

but it tells me

```
[ERROR] The selected switch /Users/Louis/git/temp/learn-ocaml is not installed.
```

Answer (score 1):

To select a switch<sup>1</sup> in Emacs within the Tuareg mode, use the `tuareg-opam-update-env` command, e.g., `M-x tuareg-opam-update-env`. It will allow you to select a switch, including local switches.

Once a switch is selected, make sure that your project (the code that you're developing) is rebuilt. You can issue `dune build` command, or, if you just want to get Merlin work, then `dune build @check` will suffice.

Last, but not least, the error message,

```
[ERROR] The selected switch /Users/Louis/git/temp/learn-ocaml is not installed.
```

indicates that you're specifying the path to the switch incorrectly or your switch is not properly installed. Try re-installing it from scratch paying attention to any error messages (there should be none of them).

---

<sup>1)</sup> I presume that by repository you mean an opam *switch* -- an installation of a compiler together with packages.

Comment: thanks! I will try to re-install my switch to see if that works